# Why is $m(n)\approx\log_2(n)$?

Tags: probability-theory, estimation

> Why is $m(n)\approx\log_2(n)$ ?

If $m(n)=\inf\{m:2^{-m}m^{-3/2}\le\frac1n\}$, taking log of $m(n)$ I get $-m(n)-\frac32\log_2(m(n))\le-\log_2(n)$

(This appears in the solution of an exercise in Rick Durret's Probability Theory and Examples)

[image]

Comment: Let $m=m(n)$ then, by definition of the infimum, $$2^{-m}m^{-3/2}\leqslant\tfrac1n<2^{-(m-1)}(m-1)^{-3/2}.$$ For one direction, note that $2^m<2n(m-1)^{-3/2}\leqslant n$, in particular $m<\log_2(2n)$. Likewise, $2^m\geqslant nm^{-3/2}$ hence, using the upper bound of $m$ previously shown, $2^m\geqslant n(\log_2(2n))^{-3/2}$. To sum up, $$\log_2(n)-\tfrac32\log_2\log_2(2n)\leqslant m<\log_2(n)+1,$$ which should suffice to conclude.

Comment: Where can I find the solution of the book?

Answer (score 1):

Since $2^{-m} m^{-3/2}$ is a decreasing function of $m$, $m(n)$ is approximately the value that makes the inequality into an equality, that is $$2^{-m(n)} m(n)^{-3 / 2} \approx \frac{1}{n} ,$$
or equivalently
$$m(n) + \tfrac{3}{2} \log_2 m(n) \approx \log_2 n .$$
For large $m$ we have that $$m(n) \gg \tfrac{3}{2} \log_2 m(n) ,$$ so the contribution of the second term is relatively small, leaving
$$m(n) \approx \log_2 n .$$